# Finding which cron jobs are scheduled to run at some future date/time X

Tags: cron

Is there a way to "query" a crontab to find which cron jobs run at some arbitrary date/time, or during a certain range of times?

For example, determine which will be run at sometime between 14:00 and 16:00 today, will run next Saturday at 10:00, or run every Sunday?

There are a lot of jobs scheduled, so reading all the crontabs by hand isn't really an option.

Comment: one of the solution can be to make timestamps, and redirect it to your monitoring system, in that case you can make script/check that actually checks what is executed and when

Comment: @klerk:Timestamps?Where from the cronjobs?I can not modify them as they are too many and all don't belong to me but other users.

Comment: @klerk:I mean how does linux when it should run a job? Some how there exists some kind of code that can interpret the crontab entries.Right?

Comment: your question is to confused, and not rational, cron entries are scheduled with your system time. So everything that is scheduled it will be executed. You need some metric, you can colect all entris from all users and put in script and redirect it to you monitoring system, at least this will be my solution

Comment: @klerk Seems perfectly clear. OP is trying to answer the question: "At 3pm tomorrow, which jobs will crond run?" and several variants on that theme.

Comment: @Jim I've edited your question in an attempt to make it clearer. I'm not entirely sure I've succeeded, as I think it was pretty clear to start with. Feel free to revert my edit or improve it further.

Comment: @Jim You might find what you want here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/137173/2100043  - From there you just need to get creative with you command line filtering tools.

Comment: @derobert:You got my question exactly!

Comment: @BriGuy:Listing all jobs from users in the OP you posted seems a simple task related to actually interpreting when each job is expected to be executed. How does linux modules do it?I mean somehow they "understand" that an entry is to be run at time X or day Y

Comment: @Jim well, crond itself has an implementation, but I'm not sure how to ask crond for that info. This seems like such an obvious thing to want, that there *must* be a tool to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I found this tool called [cronviz](https://github.com/federatedmedia/cronviz) which will show you a graphical representation of your crontab entries.

*excerpt*

> You have a problem: something's causing performance issues on the application server between 1 and 4 AM, and the cron jobs seem a likely culprit.
>
> Naturally, you eyeball your crontab to find out what's running during those hours.
>
> Now you have two problems.
>
> Over time, cron jobs accrete into an impenetrable, opaque mass of text. Trying to get a comprehensive sense of all the various run times, and finding patterns therein, can be exceedingly difficult. Crontabs are written for computers to interpret -- not humans.

*Example screenshot*

[image: ss #1]