# Getting crontab events that would happen given a start date/time

Tags: cron, reboot

Let's suppose we have a crontab scheduling some commands on an RPi project, and these commands toggle a status of a flag. The box could go out of power, and then reboot. I want to have the flag status at the correct state if the box was continuously working.

**My Idea:**
Having a task on the reboot that:

1. recovers the last date of a known state ( this should be easy, I
   could save a log entry in a file, and the date of that file is the
   "last well know state date" )
2. asks crontab to have the list of event that would happen in that lapse, and with these compute the new status.
3. done, work as usual :)

Let me know if there is a smarter way in doing so, and if not, how can I achieve point 2?

Comment: So actually you want a cron program that can output the command's it would have executed from time.start to time.end. I don't know of such an option. The rest of your request has nothing to do with the cron program, but with the commands you use in there. If you just have one job with a simple timeline in crontab, that should be quite simple. Check this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139416/finding-which-cron-jobs-are-scheduled-to-run-at-some-future-date-time-x?rq=1

Comment: the article you point catch the problem I have, but instead of a graphical app, I need the system call to achieve the same, without reimplementing crontab myself

Comment: If the interval between scheduled tasks is a day or longer, you can use [anacron](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/), which will take care of performing any scheduled tasks that are missed due to system downtime.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes I read something abut that, it replay the events with a certain delay, but this will result on an up-down of a relay driving a 1kw load, not what I want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not an out of the box task. I found a library in python:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab
that allow to find a "schedule" for a single job:

```
schedule = job.schedule(date_from=datetime.now())
...
datetime = schedule.get_next()
```

That is exactly the needing. Looping from `date_from` last reboot date while `datetime` less than now.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` will not give you a list of events. What it can do is start your script on a regular basis. Have the script do the following:

1. read a date-time-stamp from a configuration file into var X
2. increment X with a pre determined event interval (e.g. 60 minutes)
3. while X < current date-time execute the rest of the script and write X to the configuration file and repeat 2
4. (you might want to wait a minimum time in the loop)

That way the script, even if the machine goes down while it is running, will toggle the flag the number of times you want. Since the script doesn't do anything if the date-time-stamp file is not older than the interval, you can call it from the cron job much more often than it would have to run. That way catching up after a reboot doesn't have to happen (on average) after half the interval time. (e.g. schedule the script to run every five minutes). You will have to use a lock to prevent a script running twice (while one is trying to catch up after a poweroff).

Comment: I wouldnt do so as I have to write a program from scratch. I just looking for a solution exists leveraging  existing tools.

Comment: @FelicePollano You wanted cron to give you the list of events, it will not. What other tools will you leverage?

Comment: no idea, since I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the status to non-volatile storage i.e. `/var/tmp/status_task_x` and read the last set status from that same file on the next run? In that case it should survive a reboot.

In a crontab example:

```
* * * * * status_task_x=$(<"/var/tmp/status_task_x") /path/to/run_task_x $status_task_x
```

Have the task script write the output to `/var/tmp/status_task_x`

Comment: It does not work, by doing so I just set the last flag status before power down, not the status it would be now, after all the events occured since power down.

Comment: I'm sorry, in that case I think I just don't understand what you really want.